# How to rotate each particle on its axis in a Particle system in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making a space scene in which I am using a particle system to make group of asteroids,
I want to rotate each asteroids on its axis. I am using following code for making a particle system.

```
var asteroidGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
for(var i=0;i<=10000;i++)
{
    asteroidGeometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( Math.random()*10000-5000,  Math.random()*10000-5000, Math.random()*10000-5000 ) );

}
var asteroidtexture= THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/asteroids.png");
var asteroidMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({color: 'white',size:500,map:asteroidtexture,alphaTest: 0.8});
asteroids = new THREE.ParticleSystem(asteroidGeometry,astroidMaterial);

scene.add(asteroids);
```

If I will do something like

```
asteroid.position.x +=0.1;
```

then this will rotate whole system. Is it possible to rotate each particle on its on axis?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle that reproduces your problem?

Comment: My problem is just I want to access each particle of particle system. Is it possible? I am new to Three.js thats why I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual vertices in a `THREE.Geometry` instance are accessible via its `vertices` array.

I found a [tutorial](http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/) that explains how to animate particles in a particle system independently. Here's the relevant section of the `update` animation loop with some minor modifications.

```
function update() {

    var pCount = particleCount;
    while (pCount--) {

        var particle = particles.vertices[pCount];

        if (particle.position.y < -200) {
            particle.position.y = 200;
            particle.velocity.y = 0;
        }

        particle.velocity.y -= Math.random() * .1;

        particle.position.addSelf(particle.velocity);
    }

    particleSystem.geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimFrame(update);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. it will surely help me!